# Quake Live under Firefox 17, Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: 12.10, ati, firefox, acer

I've got the following problem, I am trying to start `Quake Live` on `Firefox 17` under `Ubuntu 12.10`.

I downloaded the plugin, which installed correctly, downloaded some maps... But when I try to start the game, I can only hear some garbled music and that's all. I cannot see anything from the game, like if the plugin has crashed.

Before anyone tries to say this is a clone, no it's not. [How do I play Quake Live?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/43480/how-do-i-play-quake-live) doesn't even come close to my problem... Also, it seem that `Windows` and `Firefox` combination work for some people.

My question is:

1) Does anyone has a Quake Live running, at least on `Firefox 17`?

2) If not, where should I start digging to check the logs/debug to see what's actually going on?

Comment: Hey @Melon, I can see you've done a lot of suggested edits! It's great that you want to tidy up, but we prefer that you don't do single tag edits. They bung up the review queue and waste 2k+ user's time. It takes 2 of them to review, but only 1 to actually do an edit, so it uses our time in an inefficient way. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm having this problem too. I don't have specific answers to both of your questions but I can suggest a workaround by using qlprism (http://www.qlprism.us/). This works beautifully for me (I added a shortcut to quake live on my Unity bar).